# Auto related or similar products based on products title

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I'm trying to create an automatic display similar(related) products system if product stock is less than 15.
Related products are displayed according to the title of the main product.
Some similar products are replicated other products to.
What would be the best solution to avoid this?

```
function getRecommendedList($product, $brand, $cod, $code_array, $last_code){
    global $pdoconnect;
    $image         = new Image();
    $cur_page      = $_GET['page'];
    $last_code     = array();

    $product_terms = explode(' ', $product);
    $case          = " LCASE(p.titlu) LIKE '%" .strtolower(implode("%' AND LCASE(p.titlu) LIKE '%", $product_terms))."%'";

    $stmt          = $pdoconnect->prepare("SELECT 
                               p.id AS pid, p.titlu AS titlu, 
                               p.alias AS alias, p.gramaj AS gramaj,
                               p.prettotal AS prettotal, p.cod AS cod,
                               p.poza AS poza, p.categorie AS categorie,
                               c.seo AS seo 
                               FROM produse p
                               INNER JOIN categorii c 
                              ON p.categorie=c.id 
                              WHERE ".$case." AND p.vizibil='1' 
                              AND p.brand=:brand 
                              AND p.cod !=:cod 
                              AND p.cod 
                              NOT IN ('" . implode($code_array, "', '") . "') 
                              AND p.cod 
                              NOT IN ('" . implode($last_code, "', '") . "')");
    $stmt->bindValue(':brand', $brand, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':cod', $cod, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    $total_recommended  = $stmt->rowCount();
    $recommended        = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // echo $stmt->debugDumpParams();

    $max_results        = 3;

    /*Check if there are more than 3 results for the product*/
    if($total_recommended > $max_results){
        $total_recommended = $max_results;
    }

    if($total_recommended > 0){
        for ($i=0; $i < $total_recommended; $i++) { 
            $produs['pid'][]          = $recommended[$i]['pid'];
            $produs['titlu'][]        = ucwords(strtolower($recommended[$i]['titlu']));
            $produs['cod'][]          = $recommended[$i]['cod'];
            $produs['prettotal'][]    = $recommended[$i]['prettotal'];
            $produs['gramaj'][]       = $recommended[$i]['gramaj'];
            $produs['categorie'][]    = $recommended[$i]['categorie'];
            $produs['alias'][]        = $recommended[$i]['alias'];
            $produs['seo'][]          = $recommended[$i]['seo'];

            if(file_exists(PATH . "/media/images/".$recommended[$i]['poza'])){
                $produs['foto'][]  = 
                WEBSITE . "/media/images/".$image->resize($recommended[$i]['poza'], 45, 45);
            } else {
                $produs['foto'][]  = 
                WEBSITE . "/media/images/".$image->resize('www.jpg', 45, 45);
            }
        }

        return $produs;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function is used in a foreach loop

```
    if($items['stoc'] < 15){
        $smartyProduse['recommended'][] =
        getRecommendedList($items['titlu'], $items['brand'], $items['cod'], $code_array[0]);    
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I would recommend splitting your product name (*`$product`*) into different parts by assumed human reading, for example, if the name is camel cased (eg `$camelCasedVariableName`) you can split it (eg `camel, Cased, Variable, Name`) . normally database column names are **split either by  casing or by underscores( _ )** then you could do a search for similarities to each part. try to **eliminate words like *'the', 'it'* and *'is'* for better results**

Comment: Will do, i was planning it

Comment: # Sarfaraaz, updated my code, but i need to find a solution for the duplicated related products on the same page

Comment: for duplicates `distinct` is helpful depending on the situation. Would OR be better then and to find more matches? or should you maybe take the first 3 items from the `$product_terms` array. remove words like *small*, *medium* etc also *12"* and stuff

Comment: For every product is running a query... i think i should putt all the related product codes in array and compare with the result

Comment: @speedy Please try to avoid creating many queries because it will slow down your server and you will need VPS without having visitors. It is known that an online store is already heavy (I am unable to see your website  - carafa.ro - as to verify the speed).

Comment: I'm working on localhost